# How can I edit these file contents?

Tags: file-extension

I am trying to edit some game files using Notepad ++ but the contents aren't showing up. The file extension is `.pas`, any ideas? Here is an image of the file.

[image]

Comment: This is not the content your looking for...

Comment: Oh, I figured it was because it said .pas. Any idea what language it is and how to reveal the content?

Comment: Well, this is not even a langage. This is just a tiny file containing one hexadecimal number. That could be anythink...